# Very Specific Keyboard Needs

Tags: keyboard

I'm in the market for a new keyboard, and I'm having trouble finding one that fits what I need.

I've seen these questions answered here and other places before, but they're usually along the lines of "What's the best keyboard?" or "What's your favorite keyboard?"

My question is:  **Is anyone aware of a keyboard that meets the following requirements / options**?
Optionally (as I want true *answers* and not opinions) how did you like the keyboard if you've used it?

Here are my requirements (please tell me if any are unreasonable or not recommended):

- Mechanical Keys (Topre, Cherry MX Brown, Cherry MX Clear, Cherry MX Blue, in that order)
- PS/2 (for **full** nkey rollover, and sub-10ms response)
- Double width backspace and single line enter keys, as in the example image below [image: Preferred layout]
- Wired (obviously, given PS/2)
- Laser etched keys

The following would be EXTREMELY nice, but aren't necessary:

- Braided cable sheath (I have a Logitech G500 Mouse, and I really like the cable on that)
- Gold plating on switches, contacts, cables, etc.

The following would be nice in my dreams, but I don't expect any keyboards to actually have these features:

- Numpad on left (plenty of room there on my desk, not on the right)

I **do not** need media controls or special function keys.  I would like to have a fully programmable keyboard (a la Optimus Maximus), but I don't see myself using such a feature very frequently.

*For reference, I would use the keyboard 55% for coding, 25% for web browsing, 10% for writing (emails, letters, etc.) and 10% for gaming.*

All of the "requirements" are such, but the single line enter key is a deal breaker.

The [Das Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkwes.png) (pictured) comes close, but the Cherry MX Blue switches and USB-only are big turnoffs (mostly the USB, though I don't think I'd be happy with the Blue switches), and the added USB hub creates complexity that I'd rather not take away from the overall durability of the keyboard.

The [Steelseries 7G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlDDi.jpg) comes **very** close, but the tiny backspace key and extra large enter key turn me completely off of it.  Otherwise, I love the specs.

***Is there such a keyboard in existence?***

Comment: look here http://www.pckeyboard.com/  Also.

Comment: Are you sure the second keyboard is actually pictured in its north America variant and not just the e.g. British layout reused? I'd call them and ask. Afaik it's uncommon for US keyboard to have this enter key format, and a key between left shift and z.

Comment: @DanielBeck I've heard that comment before, but [this image](http://steelseries.com/wp-content/uploads/SteelSeries-7G-6.jpg) seems to indicate that the US version also has the large enter key and small backspace key.  However, I will make an effort to contact them, since this keyboard is so close to what I want.

Comment: just curious, do you actually *need* nkro? in most cases 6kro is enough, and when typing as opposed to gaming, its rarely an issue.. Also, some modern USB keyboards seem to have NKRO, or anti ghosting technologies in them. Tthe extra large enter key is the iso layout, which, amusingly, i prefer and have issues finding. You'll also want to take a look at some smaller companies - leopold, filco and ducky are mentioned quite a lot in keyboard enthusiast circles, and might fit your requirements

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I might not _need_ nkro, but I know I've hit the limit on my current keyboard - where the limit is something like 4kro or 5kro - quite frequently.  I do like to get options that will "never" be limited, but I suppose nkro is a little over the top.  **edit**: I think my keyboard is 2kro, with modifiers.  6kro (and nkro with PS/2 adapter) might be plenty.  The Das S Professional Silent is looking better and better.

Comment: @rockerest: The Das Keyboard is ridiculously expensive.  Consider the Cherry G80-3000 series, which come in a lot of different variants.  There will be a model with everything you want, but you will need to go for a UK layout if you do not want a single-line Enter key, as that is the standard for the US.

Comment: I think he *wants* a enter key thats not L or inverted shaped, so a US keyboard would do.

Comment: Other than the need for nkro, and ps/2 the standard razer black widow ticks off most of those boxes - down to full programmability with a suitable driver.

Comment: @paradroid If you're going for a mechanical keyboard, sadly, you will have to pay a premium for it. The Das may be a bit on the high side, comparatively (to keyboards in general) but there are many keyboards out there even more expensive, and I think it's more average as far as mechanical keyboards go.

Comment: @sidran32: I have three Cherry keyboards which I have bought over the years for not much more than the price of one Das Keyboard, and they have the same Cherry MX mechanical switches.  The IBM Model M keyboards from Unicomp also cost less, and so do Filco's, last time I looked.

Comment: I feel bad now ! My keyboard is about 8 years old and cost $10. Best one i ever had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Das Keyboard does come in a variant with Cherry MX Brown switches. I have one of those specifically for the office, just so you know (since you mentioned it as being close). They also all come with USB to PS/2 adapters, and do support N-key rollover when using the PS/2 adapter.

I have not seen a modern keyboard with a numpad on the left before. However, I have seen external USB numpads around for sale. If you don't mind a little redundancy, you could very easily satisfy your requirements by buying a keyboard that covers all that you need, sans the numpad on the left, and get an external numpad and stick that to the left of your keyboard.

A quick search can give you many options: [Numeric keypads on Bing Shopping](http://www.bing.com/shopping/search?q=numeric+keypad&go=&form=QBRE&aq=numeric+keypad&aid=&ct=&qs=n&pq=numeric+keypad&sp=&rt=Completions&tk=&spv=&sl=E&sc=&st=&ast=AAAAAAAA#x0y647)

Comment: I wouldn't mind redundancy, but my main intention is to shift the typing area closer to the physical right side of the keyboard.  So having a numpad on the right would eliminate that improvement.  However, that's not as big a deal as the required USB connection on the Das.  The Cherry MX Brown switches are an interesting note, however.  I assume you mean the Model S Professional Silent, I forgot about that one.

Comment: If you look at my most recent edit, I do mention that the Das supports n-key rollover with the included PS/2 adapter, which I believe they all come with, prepackaged.

Comment: You could also do what one of my coworkers did and train yourself to mouse left-handed. :)

Comment: or go for a tenkeyless keyboard, and have a seperate number pad